# Large Accuracy Difference: Conv2D and ConvLSTM2D

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

I was trying to compare `Conv2D` and `ConvLSTM2D` architecture to estimate high resolution image from low resolution ones. But the predictions showed large difference between two architectures. What is causing such erroneous predictions? Is it due to incorrect implementation of the architectures?

## In case of ConvLSTM2D:

```python
import numpy as np, scipy.ndimage, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, ConvLSTM2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, cohen_kappa_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
np.random.seed(123)

raw = np.arange(96).reshape(8,3,4)
data1 = scipy.ndimage.zoom(raw, zoom=(1,100,100), order=1, mode='nearest') #low res
print (data1.shape)
#(8, 300, 400)

data2 = scipy.ndimage.zoom(raw, zoom=(1,100,100), order=3, mode='nearest') #high res
print (data2.shape)
#(8, 300, 400)

X_train = data1.reshape(1, data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1)
Y_train = data2.reshape(1, data2.shape[0], data2.shape[1], data2.shape[2], 1)

model = Sequential()
input_shape = (data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1)
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same',input_shape=input_shape,return_sequences=True))
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(1, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same',return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
      batch_size=1, epochs=10, verbose=1)

y_predict = model.predict(X_train)
y_predict = y_predict.reshape(data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2])
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(data2[0,:,:].reshape(-1), y_predict[0,:,:].reshape(-1))
print (r_value**2)
```

## 0.26

## In case of Conv2D:

```python
X_train = data1.reshape(data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1)
Y_train = data2.reshape(data2.shape[0], data2.shape[1], data2.shape[2], 1)

model = Sequential()
input_shape = (data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2], 1)
model.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same',input_shape=input_shape))        
model.add(Convolution2D(1, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='sigmoid',padding='same'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          batch_size=1, epochs=10, verbose=1)
y_predict = model.predict(X_train)
y_predict = y_predict.reshape(data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2])

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(data2[0,:,:].reshape(-1), y_predict[0,:,:].reshape(-1))
print (r_value**2)
```

## 0.93

Comment: It seems that you did not train the ConvLSTM model (I can't find any line with model.fit()), so your first results are just from random weights.

Comment: yes, but still there is large difference, 0.26 vs 0.93

Comment: LSTMs (and ConvLSTM2Ds) usually work well with `tanh` end activations (and that's the default, if you don't specify anything). Try to remove the `activation="sigmoid"` setting from the `ConvLSTM2D(...)` calls and see if that improves the results. Also, as @daniel-möller mentioned, you don't have a temporal relation amongst the frames. Do you have a physical relation (are they similar in capture angle, position)? If yes, then may you could try Conv3D layers here and see how they perform.

Comment: @ldavid yes, tanh improved accuracy, and now accuracy from both are almost same. And I have temporal relation as the scene underwent physical changes. Still, the predicted images are not well, and I could not improve the `ConvLSTM2D` model in order to perform super-resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two important things may be severely affecting the results:

- You have 64 Conv2D filters against 16 ConvLSTM2D filters
- The LSTM layer is trying to understand a "movie" with all images in sequence, this is certainly more complicated than just processing individual images.

For the second point, you may try a shape of `(8,1,300,400,1)` instead. This will eliminate the time steps (and should make the LSTM work exactly as the Conv2D if we understand them correctly). But then this is useless as a recurrent layer.

Unfortunately, this is the only way to "compare" them. The LSTM layers are good for "movies" (images are frames in sequence), but this does not seem to be your case.

Comment: This model is way too small for that. You need a good model, many layers, search for a U-net, for instance.

Comment: Then, the difference problem is solved, right? Do you consider your question answered?